# Cooling down person to nK scale

Tags: soft-question

If I were able to instantaneously cool my immediate surroundings to about 7nK, what would happen to me? How long would it take me to freeze?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because utterly impossible.

Comment: At $7nK$, it will probably take less than a second before your blood becomes completely solid. Without blood circulating in your brain or heart, you would immediately pass out and die shortly after that.

Comment: is there any kind of quantitative back of the envelope calculation that can be done?